# How to capture HotKeys (accelerators) messages in a button

Tags: .net, winforms, button

I'm implementing a custom `Button` class that inherits from `System.Windows.Forms.Button`, I do a custom paint of the button, including the button text. I want to support accelerator keys (hotkeys) for my buttons.

**Little explanation**: In an standard button, when the ALT key is pressed, the accelerator character is underlined:

```
  button.Text = "&Capture screen";
```

When you press **ALT key** in the application, the button underlines the "C" charater.

So, when I paint the button text, I need to know when accelerator underlines are active or not, to draw my text underlined or not.

- How could I subscribe to receive accelerator messages?
- Is an event?
- Is a WND_PROC message?
- Is there managed code to get it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @HansPassant: It seems that this property is used to know if the control must draw the focus rectangles. How is this related with HotKeys underlines?

Comment: Oops, make that ShowKeyboardCues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect whether the Alt key was pressed inside the Paint event handler of the button, you have check the ModifierKeys property of the form:

```
    private void button1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ModifierKeys == Keys.Alt)
            button1.Text = "Alt Pressed - " + button1.Text;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but what I really need is having something that is raised when th e hotkey UI has been activated. I need to Invalidate() the control.